# How to replace img tag with attribute and specific class only

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm newbie in javascript and looking for some regex or way which can replace image tag with their attributes.

Image tag can be multiple without any unique id and I want to replace only those image tags which have particular class.

For example I've string like :

```
var str = 'hi <img dataattr1="att1" src="abc" class="img specificclass" dataattr2="att2" dataattr3="att3" /> <img dataattr1="newatt1" src="abc" class="img specificclass"  dataattr2="newatt2" dataattr3="newatt3" /> some more tag <img dataattr1="moreatt1" src="abc" class="img specificclass"  dataattr2="moreatt2" dataattr3="moreatt3" /> <img dataattr2="noreplace" src="abc" class="img" /> end';
```

so its output should be like this :

```
hi :::att2::: :::newatt2::: some more tag :::moreatt2::: <img data-attr1="noreplace" src="abc" class="img" /> end
```

What I tried till now is :

```
var str = 'hi <img dataattr1="att1" src="abc" class="img specificclass" dataattr2="att2" dataattr3="att3" /> <img dataattr1="newatt1" src="abc" class="img specificclass"  dataattr2="newatt2" dataattr3="newatt3" /> some more tag <img dataattr1="moreatt1" src="abc" class="img specificclass"  dataattr2="moreatt2" dataattr3="moreatt3" /> <img dataattr2="noreplace" src="abc" class="img" /> end';

var rgx = /<img[^>]*class="specificclass"[^>]*>/;

var regex = /<img.*?dataattr2='(.*?)'/;
var src = regex.exec(str)[1]
str = str.replace(rgx,src);

console.log(str);
```

but its giving an error and I'm not if its even right way to do it or not

Comment: By far, the best way to do this is to parse the HTML and use the resulting DOM fragment. [Attempts to parse HTML with regex are doomed to fail.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use regex for this, it's famously brittle and problematic for non-regular texts like HTML.

Instead, I'd use the DOM parser built into the browser (you've tagged jQuery, so I'm assuming you're doing this on a browser or in another environment with a DOM):

```js
var str = 'hi <img dataattr1="att1" src="abc" class="img specificclass" dataattr2="att2" dataattr3="att3" /> <img dataattr1="newatt1" src="abc" class="img specificclass"  dataattr2="newatt2" dataattr3="newatt3" /> some more tag <img dataattr1="moreatt1" src="abc" class="img specificclass"  dataattr2="moreatt2" dataattr3="moreatt3" /> <img dataattr2="noreplace" src="abc" class="img" /> end';

// Parse it and wrap it in a div
var frag = $("<div>").append($.parseHTML(str));
// Find the relevant images
frag.find("img.specificclass[dataattr2]").each(function() {
  // Replace the image with a text node containing :::[dataattr2]:::
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.replaceWith(document.createTextNode(":::" + $this.attr("dataattr2") + ":::"));
});
// Get the HTML of the result
var str = frag.html();

console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```